# mm.cfg settings in Flash Player 10,2,159,1 (Debug)

Tags: flash

Some of the [settings in the mm.cfg file](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/) don't seem to work in the Debug Flash Player 10,2,159,1 on Windows 7 while some others do work.

`AS3Trace` *does* work and produce the intended output in flashlog.txt, while all of `AS3Verbose`, `AS3StaticProfile`, `AS3DynamicProfile` *don't* work and produce no output in the file.

My whole mm.cfg looks like this:

```
AS3Verbose=0
AS3Trace=0
AS3StaticProfile=1
AS3DynamicProfile=0
ErrorReportingEnable=0
TraceOutputFileEnable=1
TraceOutputFileName=C:\Users\snip\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\flashlog.txt
TraceOutputBuffered=1
MaxWarnings=0
```

Most information about mm.cfg I've been able to find is either very old (and thus likely outdated) or incomplete.

Is there a way to utilize all of the mentioned settings with the latest player version? Have the setting names changed? Is there some other setting I'm missing? I'm especially interested in getting the `AS3*Profile` settings to work.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to issue in the debug player environment, such as [Chrome's built-in plugin](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/wiki/Troubleshooting), [Flashbug](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/942980), or simple [instability](http://jpauclair.net/2010/02/10/mmcfg-treasure/) of these undocumented settings. [TheMiner](http://www.sociodox.com/theminer/faq.html) may be worth a try for future reference.